# Turning automatic nulls off for inserts to FoxPro tables through NHibernate using JetDriver isn't working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, null, oledb, foxpro

I'm using NHibernate with Burrow and Fluent to shuttle data from SQLServer2005 into a directory full of FoxPro 7 dbf's.

When I try to save a new record through Burrow's GenericDAO, I get an exception that boils down to "Field XXX does not accept null values," where field XXX is a NOT NULL field that is not being mapped at all because it is unimportant and is to be left blank.

I ran into this before when directly using ADO.Net & OleDbConnection's, and found that adding ";NULL=OFF" to the connection string solved the problem.

I've tried "NULL=OFF", "NULL=NO" in the connection string as well as "VFPOLEDB" & "VFPOLEDB.1" for provider.  It still tries to automatically insert NULLs into fields missing from the "INSERT (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ? ...)" statement (i.e., those fields I did not map).

Any ideas?

Here is my fluent config for the FoxPro tables:

```
string connString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source="
  + @"D:\Documents\Work\Projects\OurProjects\Clients\Client1\Testing\Data"
  + ";NULL=NO;";

Fluently.Configure(nhCfg)
  .Database(JetDriverConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connString)
  .Dialect<GenericDialect>().Driver<OleDbDriver>())
  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(
    Assembly.Load("OurProduct.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")))
  .BuildConfiguration();
```

And the mapping class, the actual table these are being inserted into has a couple dozen unmapped fields, all NOT NULL and they all should be blank on new records:

```
    public class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
    {
        public ClientMap() {
            Id(x => x.PersonId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
            Map(x => x.LastName).Length(15);
            Map(x => x.FirstName).Length(15);
            Map(x => x.MiddleName).Column("midname").Length(1);
            Map(x => x.Address1).Length(40);
            Map(x => x.Address2).Length(40);
            Map(x => x.City).Length(20);
            Map(x => x.State).Length(2);
            Map(x => x.ZipCode).Length(9);
            Map(x => x.Gender).Length(30);
            Map(x => x.Ethnicity).Length(30);
            Map(x => x.MaritalStatus).Column("marital").Length(30);
            Map(x => x.LivingArrangement).Column("livarrange").Length(30);
            Map(x => x.PovertyLevel).Column("povlevel").Length(30);
            Map(x => x.BirthDate);
            Map(x => x.AssessmentNotes).Column("assnotes");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following appears to resolve the issue, but I believe would require doing for each new unit of work (BurrowFramework initialization).

```
        var sess = bf.GetSession(typeof(Client));

        var dbCmd = sess.Connection.CreateCommand();

        dbCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        dbCmd.CommandText = "SET NULL OFF";

        sess.Transaction.Enlist(dbCmd);


        dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The OLE-DB property [DBPROP_VFPOLEDB_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977005%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the equivalent of SET NULL.

Comment: Where and how is it used? Possibly your solution is the best, but not giving an example...